# Whats the impact of changing image styles and jpeg compression

Tags: media

I've inherited a 10-year-old image-heavy (tens of thousands of images) Drupal 7 site. I'm moving the site to a full-width grid, and before I break anything, would someone be able to tell me what happens to the images after you change an image style, or the image compression ratio?

Does this cause the server to process each image and regenerate the images which would take forever and possibly break things. Or does this happen on a page load basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 10,000 will **not** be regenerated at the same time. They are regenerated on page load basis. Depending on how big in size these images are, will affect how fast they are regenerated. Once they are regenerated, should load fast from then on.

The old image style will get auto deleted from the /styles folder.